# Type Error when trying to subset data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a subset of a dataframe based on a value of a column. However when I run my code I get the following error

> TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed.

My code is below, thank you!

```
#read data
df = pd.read_csv('Workbook.csv')

#turn certain columns into categories
df['Class'] = df['Class'].astype('category')
df['Pos'] = df['Pos'].astype('category')
df['Drafted'] = df['Drafted'].astype('category')

#subset of undrafted players
df_sosByDrafted = df[['SOS','Drafted']]
df_sos_undrafted = df_sosByDrafted.loc(df_sosByDrafted['Drafted'] == 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use square brackets after `.loc`!

```
df_sos_undrafted = df_sosByDrafted.loc[df_sosByDrafted['Drafted'] == 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your objective correctly, you can use the following line of code to get the subset of all rows (in a subset of only the SOS and Drafted columns) with a value of 0 in the Drafted column:

```
df_sos_undrafted = df_sosByDrafted[ df_sosByDrafted[ 'Drafted' ] == 0 ]
```